# mysql query in a loop using left join with columns the same name

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a search form with multiple fields to search. Data is in 2 different tables depending on what you are searching for in each field.

I have a column that has the same name in each table. Because of this it obviously gives me the sql error of: Column 'state' in where clause is ambiguous

It would not be a problem if the form fields were not in a loop. I am new to php and this is trying me.

I have tried to use aliases in the SELECT for mysql but now i cant target them because it doesnt come through correctly.

Here is what i have for my form:

```
 <form method="post" action="index.php">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Name:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="display_name" id="display_name" class="display_name tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type name of person"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Service Type:</td>
                                    <td><select name="service_name">
                                          <option>
                                         <?php
            $query1 = "SELECT service_type FROM nfw_service_type ORDER BY id_num";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1); @$num_results1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
        ?>

        <?php /*Loop through each row and display records */
            for($i=0; $i<$num_results1; $i++) { $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
        ?>  

        <?php // echo 'Name' .$row['ssfullname'] . 'email' . $row['ssemail'] . "\n"; ?>

            <option value="<?php print $row1['service_type']; ?>"><?php print $row1['service_type']; ?></option>

        <?php // end loop
    } ?>
                                        </select></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Suburb:</td>
                                        <input type="text" name="suburb" id="suburb" class="suburb tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type name of person"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>State:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="usersstate2">
                                          <option>
                                          <option value="qld">QLD</option>
                                          <option value="sa">SA</option>
                                          <option value="nt">NT</option>
                                          <option value="wa">WA</option>
                                          <option value="vic">VIC</option>
                                          <option value="tas">TAS</option>
                                          <option value="act">ACT</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Type:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="user_type">
                                          <option>
                                          <option value="franchise">Franchisee</option>
                                          <option value="regional">Regional</option>
                                          <option value="state">State</option>
                                          <option value="national">National</option>
                                          <option value="office">Headoffice Staff</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Active:</td>
                                     <td>
                                        <select name="active1">
                                          <option></option>
                                          <option value="1">Active</option>
                                          <option value="0">Not Active</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </form>
```

And here is the code once the form is submitted:

```
    <?php
                                    // SEARCH

                                    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                                        // define the list of fields
                                        $fields = array('display_name', 'service_name', 'suburb', 'nfw_users.usersstate2', 'user_type', 'nfw_users.active1');
                                        $conditions = array();

                                        // loop through the defined fields
                                        foreach($fields as $field){
                                            // if the field is set and not empty
                                            if(isset($_POST[$field]) && $_POST[$field] != '') {

                                                $example = $_POST[$field];
                                                // create a new condition while escaping the value inputed by the user (SQL Injection)
                                                $conditions[] = "`$field` LIKE '%{$example}%'";
                                            }


                                        // builds the query
                                          $query = "SELECT
                                                    nfw_users.id_num,
                                                    nfw_users.display_name,
                                                    nfw_users.first,
                                                    nfw_users.last,
                                                    nfw_users.email,
                                                    nfw_users.mobile,
                                                    nfw_users.landline,
                                                    nfw_users.user_type,
                                                    nfw_users.suburb,
                                                    nfw_users.active AS active1,
                                                    nfw_users.state AS usersstate2,
                                                    nfw_services.state AS servicesstate3
                                                    FROM
                                                    nfw_users
                                                    left JOIN nfw_services ON nfw_services.user_id = nfw_users.id_num
                                                    LEFT JOIN nfw_service_areas ON nfw_service_areas.service_id = nfw_services.id_num ";

                                        if(count($conditions) > 0) {
                                            // append the conditions


                                            $query .= "WHERE " . implode (' AND ', $conditions) ." GROUP BY nfw_users.id_num ORDER BY nfw_users.display_name"; // you can change to 'OR', but I suggest to apply the filters cumulative
                                        }
                                        }}
                                        $result = mysql_query($query);
var_dump($query); 
                                        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                                                while ($score = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                                    $active1 = $score['active1'];
                                                  if ($active1=='1') {
                                                    $activeother = "<i class='fa fa-check' style='color:green;'></i>";
                                                  }
                                                  else {
                                                    $activeother = "<i class='fa fa-times' style='color:red;'></i>";
                                                  }

                                            $content = "<tr><td>" . $score['display_name'] . "</td><td>" . $score['first'] . "</td><td>" . $score['last'] . "  </td><td>" . $score['email'] . " </td><td> " . $score['mobile'] . " </td><td> " . $score['landline'] . "</td><td>$activeother</td><td> " . $score['user_type'] . "</td><td> " . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($score['date_join'])) . "</td><td class='invoicing-columns'><a class='btn btn-yellow' href='view-invoices.php?id=" . $score['id_num'] . "'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></a></td><td class='invoicing-columns'><a class='btn btn-red' href='del-customers.php?id=" . $score['id_num'] . "' onclick='return check();' class='delete'><i class='fa fa-minus-circle'></i></a></td></tr>";
                                            echo $content;
                                            }
                                            }
                                        ?>
```

Yes i do know one part isnt using sqli and i will fix that.  :)

Comment: Use `tablename.state` to indicate which table the column comes from.

Comment: Do you mean make the form field name="tablename.state" ?

I did try that, no go  :(

Comment: The form field doesn't have to have the same name as the column in the query. You need to translate from the form field to the appropriate `tablename.state`.

Comment: Im not sure i follow.

Comment: Do you mean capturing it using a if statement. So if $field = state etc etc ?

Comment: You can do that. Or you could have an associative array that maps form field names to database columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but your implementation of alias names is a bit off. To assign an alias use the format `sometable as somealiasname`. Use an alias different than your table names  (t1, t2, t4,etc. are common).

Try this:

```
//as long as you only use each attribute name once, you could do it like this:
$fields=array();
$fields['t1'] = array('display_name', 'service_name', 'suburb', 'state', 'user_type', 'active');

$fields['t2'] = array('some_other_field_in_t2','yet_another_field_in_t2');
$fields['t3'] = array('some_other_field_in_t3','yet_another_field_in_t3');

foreach($fields as $table=>$these_fields){
    foreach($these_fields as $field){
        if(isset($_POST[$field]) && $_POST[$field] != '') {
            $example = $_POST[$field];
            // TODO: don't forget to sanitize inputs
            $conditions[] = "`$table`.`$field` LIKE '%{$example}%'";
        }
    }
}


$conditions[] = "t1.`$field` LIKE '%{$example}%'"; //for values are coming from t1 (nfw_users)

$conditions[] = "t2.`$field` LIKE '%{$example}%'"; //as long as all values are coming from t1 (nfw_users)
```

Alternatively, you could try this approach to map unique keys to a specific location if you want to pull data from columns in different tables that have the same column name:

```
$fields=array();
$fields['display_name']=array('table'=>'t1','attribute'=>'display_name');
$fields['service_name']=array('table'=>'t1','attribute'=>'service_name');
$fields['suburb']=array('table'=>'t1','attribute'=>'suburb');
$fields['state']=array('table'=>'t1','attribute'=>'state');
$fields['user_type']=array('table'=>'t1','attribute'=>'user_type');
$fields['active']=array('table'=>'t1','attribute'=>'active');
$fields['some_other_field_in_t2']=array('table'=>'t2','attribute'=>'some_other_field');
$fields['yet_another_field_in_t2']=array('table'=>'t2','attribute'=>'yet_another_field');
$fields['some_other_field_in_t3']=array('table'=>'t3','attribute'=>'some_other_field');
$fields['yet_another_field_in_t3']=array('table'=>'t3','attribute'=>'yet_another_field');

foreach($fields as $field=>$field_data){

    if(isset($_POST[$field]) && $_POST[$field] != '') {
        $example = $_POST[$field];
        // TODO: don't forget to sanitize inputs
        $conditions[] = "`$field_data['table']`.`$field_data['attribute']` LIKE '%{$example}%'";
    }

}
```

Either way....

```
$query = "SELECT
    t1.id_num,
    t1.display_name,
    t1.first,
    t1.last,
    t1.email,
    t1.mobile,
    t1.landline,
    t1.user_type,
    t1.suburb,
    t1.active AS active1,
    t1.state AS usersstate2,
    t2.state AS servicesstate3
    FROM
    nfw_users as t1
    LEFT JOIN nfw_services as t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.id_num
    LEFT JOIN nfw_service_areas as t3 ON t2.service_id = t1.id_num";


$query .= "WHERE " . implode (' AND ', $conditions) ." GROUP BY t1.id_num ORDER BY t1.display_name";
```

This page discusses aliases if you'd like more examples:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: His problem is in the `WHERE` clause that he constructs using the `$conditions` array. You haven't shown how to make that generate `t1.state` or `t2.state`.

Comment: You don't _have_ to use aliases, you can use the actual table names like he is in his query.

Comment: @Elgoots ... If you replace your `WHERE` statement with `WHERE 1` (or just exclude it, does the query succeed?

Comment: if i comment out the WHERE all together it just shows ALL RECORDS of everything. Barmar is correct. That is the issue i am having. its the $conditions that im trying to work out.    :(

Comment: Ah... ok, I just edited my answer to include an alias (although, as Barmar said, since you're only joining each table once it isn't strictly necessary).

Try including an alias, or table name if you're sticking with that, when you set `$conditions[]`

Comment: Also, one little bit of code I find extremely useful in these situations is PHP dBug (http://dbug.ospinto.com/). You just include the dBug.php file and then you can insert something like `new dBug($conditions);` or `new dBug($query);` and it generates a really nice graphical display of arrays, objects, strings, etc. It is really handy for troubleshooting SQL statements too because the generated output is easy to spot and doesn't get buried in your html source. I don't want to sound like an ad because I have nothing to do with that site, it just really is very handy.

Comment: Just realized I overlooked that you had referenced other tables within $fields. Just edited answer again to include some edits on that line as well.

Comment: Thank you! That got it! finally got it going. Whoo. Ill definitively remember this one next time. Thanks Cragmonkey and Barmar

Comment: Oh... Now i do have another issue. What if they are not all coming from T1.....

Is there a way to tell where each form field is coming from and direct them through a different $condition on the fly.

Comment: Yes... see above. I proposed two different ways to achieve that.

Comment: i got it work. I put it inside the loops of $conditions and created a if statement to check for those couple of fields that needed to check against t2 instead of t1. Works great. Thank you for your patience and answers  :)